# Проблемы с Null-коалесцентным оператором

Tags: c#, unity3d

Правильно ли я понимаю, что следующие конструкции должны быть эквивалентны:

```
 MeshCollider collider = go.GetComponent<MeshCollider>();
 MeshCollider meshCollider = collider != null ? collider : go.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
```

и

```
 MeshCollider collider = go.GetComponent<MeshCollider>();
 MeshCollider meshCollider = collider ?? go.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
```

Если да, то почему первая конструкция работает, а во второй я получаю null?

EDIT:
Давайте так:

```
MeshCollider collider = go.GetComponent<MeshCollider>();
//Выводит True, логично поскольку MeshCollider ещё не установлен
Debug.Log(collider == null);
//Выводит False, логично поскольку MeshCollider ещё не установлен
Debug.Log(collider != null);


MeshCollider newCollider = go.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
//Выводит False, логично поскольку MeshCollider теперь установлен
Debug.Log(newCollider == null);
//Выводит True, логично поскольку MeshCollider теперь установлен
Debug.Log(newCollider != null);


MeshCollider meshCollider1 = collider != null ? collider : newCollider;
MeshCollider meshCollider2 = collider == null ? newCollider : collider;
 MeshCollider meshCollider3 = collider ?? newCollider;

//Не логично
//Выводит Test (UnityEngine.MeshCollider), Test (UnityEngine.MeshCollider), null
Debug.LogFormat("{0}, {1}, {2}", meshCollider1, meshCollider2, meshCollider3);
```

Comment: Нет, не эквивалентны. В первом случае `GetComponent` может быть вызван 2 раза, а во втором - всегда один раз

Comment: Магии не бывает, так что либо вы что-то делаете не так, либо `GetComponent` имеет некие побочные эффекты и повторный вызов возвращает не то же самое, что и первый

Comment: @АндрейNOP, если у `go` нет `MeshCollider`,  то `GetComponent` всегда будет возвращать null

Comment: @Ziens судя по коду, `null` вам возвращает `AddComponent`

Comment: @АртёмОконечников, хорошо, а в первом случае почему не null?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, я изменил код, теперь `GetComponent` вызывается один раз, но проблема осталась

Comment: @Ziens Если я ничего не путаю, то проблема в перегруженном операторе (==, !=) https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_eq.html

Comment: @АртёмОконечников: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD нужно юнити слить, тест-пример сделать, исходники посмотреть, объяснить, почему так (Судя по документации у них == и != по разному работают!). А возможности сейчас это быстро сделать нет.

Comment: @АртёмОконечников: Там в конце есть пример: `Object obj = new Object(); Debug.Log (obj == null); // true`. Очень похоже на то, что происходит.

Comment: @Ziens: А вы можете проверить следующее: `MeshCollider collider = go.GetComponent<MeshCollider>(); bool x = collider == null;` — какое значение у `x`?

Comment: @VladD как раз добавил подобный пример

Comment: @Ziens: А можете ещё вот так: `MeshCollider collider = go.GetComponent<MeshCollider>(); bool x1 = collider == null; bool x2 = object.ReferenceEquals(collider, null);`?

Comment: @VladD, x1=True, x2=False

Comment: @АртёмОконечников: Вот и подтверждение.

Comment: @Ziens: Отлично, тогда Артём Оконечников прав.

Comment: Теперь понятно почему перегрузку операторов не добавляют в Java: это зло.

Comment: @Ziens: Это само по себе не зло. Зло — перегружать операторы вот таким вот неочевидным образом.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как и предполагал @АртёмОконечников в комментариях - проблема в перегрузке операторов `==` и `!=`.

Конструкция `??` сравнивает *экземпляр* левого операнда с `null`.

Но разработчики Unity решили переопределить `UnityEngine.Object.operator ==` так, чтобы *'неинициализированный'* *экземпляр (который* `!destroyed`*)* `UnityEngine.Object` и всех его потомков возвращал `true` при сравнении с `null`.

Например:

```
MeshCollider collider = new MeshCollider();
print(collider == null); //Выведет True
```

Таким образом конструкция `??` работает не так как ожидается, если операторы сравнения перегружены